# Python pool.map with large iteratables

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite

I have a quite large table in a database (>20GB). I want to read all rows from the whith python and print them. I am using an SQLite database and Python 2.7

My first approach is quite standard. I can simpyl query all rows and iterate over them:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM large_table')
for row in cur:
    print row
```

This works as expected.

Out of curiosity I wanted to use `multiprocessing.Pool` to do the same job.

```
def consumer(data):
    print data


cur.execute('SELECT * FROM large_table')
pool = Pool(5)

pool.map(consumer, cur, chunksize=1000)
```

But this does not work at all. The `.map()` methods seems to try to load the full iteratable (large database table) into RAM. After a while all of my RAM is in use without any output.

Am I missing anything or is `pool.map` just the wrong tool for the job?

Cheers,
Tobias

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing anything or is pool.map just the wrong tool for the job?

Yes, you should use `pool.imap()` instead.  It does not "consume" all the values before dispatching to the worker processes.   It should be a drop-in fix for your code.

Comment: Thanks for teh tip! But, `pool.imap()` does not even call the passed method (in my case)

Comment: @alive-and-well: It will when you start to consume its results.  It only consumes the input when someone consumes its output.  Similar to `itertools.imap()`.  Just loop over the return value of `imap()` and discard it.

Comment: this is my code: 
`print "pool"
 for x in pool.imap(consumer, cur, chunksize=100):
  print x
 print "done"`
it simply prints "pool ...done"